# Why are my circled div not inline with the rest of li?

Tags: html, css

I am creating my custom wizard. I just try to put a "circled div" in my tabs. However my tabs are horizontal whereas my cirdcled div are.. ugly

https://jsfiddle.net/sme79azj/

html:

```
 <ul>
      <li>
           <a><div class="wizard-steps-number">
                <span class="number">1</span>
           </div>Step number 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
           <a><div class="wizard-steps-number">2</div>Step number 2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Css

```
 ul{
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0px;    }
 li {
      border: solid 1px lightgrey;
      cursor: default;
      color:black;
      display: inline;
      height:82px;
      font-size: 12px;
      margin: 0px;
      opacity: 0.5;
      padding-top: 15px;
      padding-bottom: 15px;
      padding-left: 25px;
      padding-right: 25px;

  }
.wizard-steps-number {    
  border-radius:1em;
  border:solid 1px grey;
  height:2em;
  font-size:2em;
  line-height:2em;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:2em;}
```

Comment: Perhaps a picture of the intended result would be useful. I'm having trouble determining what you're going for at the moment.

Comment: 'ugly' is not enough of explanation on what you are looking to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some properties can be applied to only block level elements. If you wants to apply them to `inline` elements then first make `inline` elements `inline-block`.

Change `display: inline` to `display: inline-block` for `li` and it will work with minor other changes as shown below:

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;

}
ul li {
  border: solid 1px lightgrey;
  cursor: default;
  color:black;
  display: inline-block;
  height:82px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.wizard-steps-number {    
  border-radius:1em;
  border:solid 1px grey;
  height:2em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size:2em;

  line-height:2em;
  text-align:center;

  color:black;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width:2em;

}
```

```html
<h1>
  My wizard doesn't have circle inline... :-(
</h1>

<ul>
  <li><a><div class="wizard-steps-number"><span class="number">1</span></div>Step number 1</a></li>
  <li><a><div class="wizard-steps-number">2</div>Step number 2</a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

without more explanation about what 'ugly' means, i made this snippet. hope it is what you are looking for...let me know

use `display:inline-block` on the `li` and `margin:0 auto` to center the circles

```css
ul{
      list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;

}
li {
        border: solid 1px lightgrey;
        cursor: default;
        color:black;
        display: inline-block;
        height:82px;
        font-size: 12px;
        margin: 0px;
        opacity: 0.5;
        padding-top: 15px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
        padding-left: 25px;
        padding-right: 25px;

    }

.wizard-steps-number {    
      border-radius:1em;
    border:solid 1px grey;
    height:2em;
  
    font-size:2em;

    line-height:2em;
    text-align:center;
    
    color:black;
     white-space: nowrap;
    width:2em;
    margin:0 auto;

}
```

```html
<h1>
My wizard doesn't have circle inline... :-(
</h1>

<ul>


<li><a><div class="wizard-steps-number"><span class="number">1</span></div>Step number 1</a></li>
 <li><a><div class="wizard-steps-number">2</div>Step number 2</a></li>
                            
                            </ul>
```

Comment: if you would read again the OP question and then my answer, you will see that i DID NOT say that what he is doing is ugly. he used that term ( ugly ) describing his problem, and i just said i don't understand what he is referring to when he says 'ugly' . please...before you comment, read carefully. thanks

Comment: ok. instead of apologizing for the rude comment, you deleted it. nice